# Joomla 3.2.1 password encryption

Tags: php, joomla, password-hash

When the user register on the site , and I look in the database joomla_users in the password table, there are password stored in the following formats:

- $P$Do8QrURFT1r0NlWf0X/grdF/aMqwqK/
- $P$DH38Lch9z508gJiop3A6u0whTity390
- ........

But not in the form as described in the documentation (MD5 + ":" + SALT):

- 1802ebc64051d5b4f4d1b408babb5020:0PHJDbnsyX05YpKbAuLYnw2VCzFMW2VK

I need to have this clarified for me, because I'm using outside script that checks for user credentials to check for password match.

In my PHP script I have code that seperates SALT from password from database:

```
$parts   = explode( ':', $password_database );
$crypt   = $parts[0];
$salt   = $parts[1];
```

But I can't do that if there is no dobule knot (:)

Comment: I'd *hope* they weren't still using MD5, it's really weak.

Comment: That's not md5, it's salted md5, which is very different though not as good as what is being used now.

Comment: yes, but this is the last joomla versio available...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this,

The following piece of code is creating Joomla standard password **(Older Version 1.5,1.7 etc)**.

```
 jimport('joomla.user.helper');
 $salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
 $crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password_choose, $salt);
 $password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

**Joomla 3.2+** introduced PHP's password algorithm **bcrypt** but it required a minimum PHP **5.3+** If you plan to use **bcrypt** make sure your server PHP version is capable for this, [read more here](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_disable_the_Strong_Passwords_feature).

The other Version of Joomla Using the following methods (**Joomla 3.x**)

```
 jimport('joomla.user.helper');
 $yourpass = JUserHelper::hashPassword($password_choose);
```

***The older algorithm also works fine in latest version too , only difference is older version creates a 65 character password and new one creates 34 character string. always go with updated version***

Also if you are using external script should include Joomla framework like below. This should at very top of your external php file

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Also you mentioned you have to check users credential then no need to check password format and all thing just use below codes after framework loads.

```
   $credentials['username'] = $data['username']; //user entered name
   $credentials['password'] = $data['password']; //users entered password
   $app = JFactory::getApplication();
   $error = $app->login($credentials, $options);
   if (!JError::isError($error)) {
    // login success
    }
  else{
    //Failed attempt
   }
```

hope it helps..

Comment: Hi. With this trying 'test' as password I am getting a 65 character string: $P$D6qfmWHlMjUFNUxiYnt5qawXZ1bOTP. But changing the password of an user to test in BD I get a 34 character string: $P$D6qfmWHlMjUFNUxiYnt5qawXZ1bOTP.
Why?

Comment: @OceanicSix How you change the password from admin side  ? its uses default joomla script or your own custom codes.It always create the password with length of 65char.

Comment: What I mean is that using what Jobin said in his first part code I got a 65 character password. 

Changing to a user its password (in backend / administrator view) and then cheking in DB what have been stored, the string has 34 characters. So it is the how joomla store passwords.

I finally get to do a 34 character encrypted password with David Fritsch code.

Comment: Both are working right ? It depends on the Version too.

Comment: I am using Joomla 3.2.1 and generate a encrypted password with that PHP code (which will have 34 character) and paste it in password column in 'XXX_user' table DB works.

Comment: @JobinJose What if my external script is not in the same project?
I have 2 different projects.

Comment: @AmolChakane you mean two Joomla installation ? The you have to use External script with loading framework options.

Comment: @JobinJose My external script is in another project, which is developed in core php.

Comment: @AmolChakane ok, both are in same public_html right ? then even your core php project can load the Joomla framework using above script. If it is in two different space you can't solve it.

Comment: @JobinJose My badluck :( Projects are in two different spaces.
But I got one Joomla component which allows remote login using curl.

Comment: Very nice. But suppose you have to decrypt it (or encrypt it) using something other than PHP, like Java?

Comment: @nemesys you can't decrypt Joomla Password!

Comment: Recent versions of Joomla use the built-in PHP [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/it/function.password-hash.php) function when available (PHP >= 5.5). That hashing function uses the "standard" bcrypt algorithm, which is available in many languages.

Answer (score 10):

Joomla's default user class no longer uses salted MD5 to hash the password. The bind function of the `JUser` class now calls `JUserHelper::hashPassword($array['password'])` to encrypt the password.

That function is currently this:

```
public static function hashPassword($password)
    {
            // Use PHPass's portable hashes with a cost of 10.
            $phpass = new PasswordHash(10, true);

            return $phpass->HashPassword($password);
    }
```

And that means that it now relies on PHPass which you can read more about here: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/. Based on reading just the intro of this site, I'm guessing that the encryption is now `bcrypt` instead of MD5, but Joomla may have overriden the default encryption.

Comment: For future visitors - this code hashes "test" to:
$P$DCeSr0.vZrpBk6GK.q8VrltNIdwetN0

Answer (score 5):

With David Fritsch answer I get to do a encrypted password as Joomla does:

```
<?php
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

    require_once( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $mainframe->initialise();

    jimport('joomla.user.helper');
    $password = "test";     
    echo "<strong>Password: </strong>" . JUserHelper::hashPassword($password);
?>
```

Note that you have to store the file in joomla root directory, or change JPATH_BASE.

Comment: For future visitors - this code outputs (Joomla 3.4.4):
Password:$2y$10$upX58HulZWgBwKps2DaB9eoi2jI90H3i.JP3aSJQ.QwJWDo62l/Cy

Comment: For future visitors, I found that actually (with Joomla! 3.5.1) the hash will be always different, even with the very same password being inserted.