# Joomla Create my own password change form

Tags: php, joomla, passwords

I want to create a simple form with input fields like old password, new password etc. I want to encrypt the new password (which is a simple text format) the same way as Joomla does. I got the technique, but my problem is I have made a simple PHP page, so what I should import or write in PHP page such that the functions of Joomla like jimport (), JUserHelper() it works.

my code is

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
echo $salt;
```

I have tried to do it by simply pasting jimport('joomla.user.helper'), but it was not working .

Comment: The really does depend on what version of Joomla you're using

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304038/joomla-3-2-1-password-encryption/21304362#21304362

Comment: @JobinJose - Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this method will change a little when they get `bcrypt` running with Joomla again.

Answer (score 0):

Import User helper and try this:

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($enteredpassword, $salt);
$passwordtobesaved = $crypt . ':' . $salt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried below code and it is working fine
    define('_JEXEC', 1 );
    define ('JPATH_BASE', dirname(*FILE*));
    define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php');
    require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php');
    require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php');
    jimport('joomla.user.helper');

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$new_p = $_POST['posted_password'];
$new_password = JUserHelper::hashPassword($new_p);
```