# Joomla 3.3.1 bcrypt inconsistent?

Tags: php, joomla, bcrypt

I am updating my login module to work with the new bcrypt scheme addet to Joomla in 3.2. Running `JUserHelper::hashPassword("test")` returns:

```
$2y$10$JlH32nPPCKtqqjuw.2p1X.0orqqSXn28eClz5Z3rDozW.j1KASN/e
```

But when the password is generated from the Joomla backend

```
$2y$10$0vJdqZDtIddQAAp2yBT7KOoFJ3BLUHCt3LS8XiZlE3dZftYHORJS2
```

is stored in the database.

I have looked for a cupple of days after something I might have missed (salt?) but I am not sure how Joomla is handling it

I have read and tryed the sugestions from [Joomla 3.2.1 password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304038/joomla-3-2-1-password-encryption).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each use of `hashPassword()` generates a password with a different salt, so the resulting values will always be different, even when the same password is used..... that's deliberate to make it more difficult for attackers.

And that's why you have a [verifyPassword()](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUserHelper.html#method_verifyPassword) method, to check the validity of the entered password

Answer (score 0):

I have to j3.4 works like this:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$testingPlainPass = "test";
$verifyPass = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($testingPlainPass, $user->password, $user->id);
if($verifyPass) {echo "So gud!";}
```

and cool method change pass:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user->password = JUserHelper::hashPassword($newpassPlainText);
$user->save();
```

Comment: You might want to improve the wording of your non-code sections a bit.