# How to encrypt the Password column in jos_users (Joomla)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, md5, joomla3.3

My aim was to import a CSV file full of user details into jos_users through Phpmyadmin. All columns match and it was imported without issue.

I have also applied user group definitions in the jos_usergroup_map table, without issue.

The list of users match with the backend side of Joomla but I cannot log into the new users in the front end. After playing around I have realized that the password column in jos_users must be encrypted to work. You can do this in the back end of joomla by re-typing the password and saving changes (and it encrypts it and works fine).

I was wondering. Is there a way to encrypt the jos_users password column in one go. Instead of going one by one?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar thread explaining the joomla password encryption.

[Joomla 3.2.1 password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304038/joomla-3-2-1-password-encryption)

Write a script which will update the password as per the joomla standards, export data from jos_users table and pass this data as input to the script.