# Joomla 3.3 crypting in java, get salt value

Tags: java, password-encryption, joomla3.3

I wanted to implement an external login using java,
but the password hashing in joomla uses md5 with a salt value to generate the hashed passwords.
How can I get the salt values to enable the login via my Java Client?

Especially the Salt values of each User.

Comment: There is now a http://joomla.stackexchange.com you might want to try moving it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla in the latest 3.3.x you are asking about does not use MD5 anymore it uses bcrypt
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315610/6096

Comment: Ok is it possible to copy this encryption method and using it in java so I can implement my own login, finally bcrypt uses a salt value too, how can I get it to make my own login in java ?

Comment: I am not an expert on that, try the sub SO on joomla.stackexchange.com but bcrypt should be able to work in java as its not a php thing

Answer (score 0):

The Salt wouldn't be a random value and you should find it in the joomla hash function for hashing the pw.

The salt for each user should be the same.

Look at the pw-hash functionality of joomla.