# How are Joomla 3 passwords encrypted?

Tags: joomla, password-hash

I'm developing a migrate script (Joomla 3 to Drupal 7).
Because I don't want to decrypt Joomla's user passwords, I want to check if the inputted password, after encryption, matches the password in my Joomla table. Just like a normal login system.

The only thing I don't know, is how Joomla's Password are encrypted in Joomla 3.x. So I want to know what happens when I enter my password in Joomla's login form.

Can anybody help me out (I prefer some PHP code)?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3.2 and above uses Bcrypt as the hashing algorithm for passwords.

Anything below Joomla 3.2 uses MD5 + Salt

Comment: Do you have a code snippet to encrypt a plain text password to an encrypted string, like Joomla uses?

Comment: @JordiFuite - Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21304362/1362108