# Joomla Encrypt Passwords for Database

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

For someone without any cryptology knowledge - I would like to know if it is possible to take a unencrypted password, and then convert it to an encrypted password that Joomla (3.3.6) will understand after it has been directly inserted into the database via SQL?

This link seems to talk about something similar but I don't think it exactly what I need to know ([Joomla 3.2.1 password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304038/joomla-3-2-1-password-encryption))

Is it possible?

Is there a ready made encryption script that can do this?

Or would I have to find someone that could do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use MySQL's MD5 function - Joomla understands passwords that are hashed using MD5. No need to create a script.

In phpMyAdmin, in the #__users table, just change the password to the one that you want and choose MD5 from the function dropdown.

Comment: default md5 encrypted password will not work with joomla , joomla using different methods.

Comment: @JobinJose It'll actually work - try it. We use it every day for our clients.

Comment: Thank you this does indeed work. I ended up using using a combination of this for a very hacky way to do it. Used phpMyAdmin to insert one record with the md5 function. Got the SQL code and then used an xls of the data to create hundreds of rows and then ran the SQL on there. At least it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to import some users data from external application ?

Then best to try some Joomla users Import extensions. bcoz it will help you to fix the password stuff. If it didn't you have to work like this.

1. Create a separate PHP file for data import or password setup.
2. load the Joomla framework to that PHP file
3. read all your users details from CSV/DB tables.
4. hash the password and write it to #__users table.

the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304038/joomla-3-2-1-password-encryption) you found is the right resource for that , I already explained everything in details there.

hope now it make sense..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store unencrypted passwords into a Joomla! user database, you are basically importing users. The best Joomla extension I know for this task, is Arra User. I used it for mass CSV imports with plain text passwords.

You could the extension [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/arra-user-migrate).